# Trying to understand google cloud function for sendgrid inbound parse

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I have a sendgrid designation url of [www.mydomain.com/mail/post](http://www.mydomain.com/mail/post). I am trying to create a google cloud function that takes an email from the inbound parse API. I cannot get the API to be triggered when an email is sent.

After reading a lot of documentation and trying to re-create demos, I still don't understand how this function will know when an email is posted from the webhook.
Can someone educate me if there is something else that is needed to simply test that when an email is sent to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), that the sendgrid webhook will post the email to the destination URL and the cloud function below will be activated?

Does the destination URL for the sendgrid incoming webhook need to be the URL for the google cloud function?

Google Cloud Function

```
app.post("/mail/post", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("test");

   functions.logger.log("test");

  return res.status(200).send();
});

app.listen(3000, console.log("Express app listening on port 
3000."));

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand I'm a noob, but boy it was hard to find the answer for this.

My solution was:

1. Not use express. I don't know what Express does really. Added layer of difficulty.
2. **IMPORTANT:** The destination URL in Sendgrid needs to be the google cloud function. This is obvious now, but wasn't then.